# Wamp server giving "It works!" on going to http://localhost

Tags: localhost

This is for a friend of mine. When he installed **WAMP server**, it installed perfectly. And then when he goes to `http://localhost` there is only 1 message that is displayed in the browser which is

## It Works!

**It does not display the WAMP homepage at all !**  He has also reintalled WAMP server like a bazillion times, but with no success, it always gives him that **It works!** message. Has anybody else here encountered the same situation? And it is not the *Port 80* problem, i checked. Please reply soon as he is not able to do his project at home because of this.

Comment: What's the problem? Sounds like it works.

Comment: It's working, is there any problem with that?

Comment: It isnt displaying the WAMP homepage :(

Comment: dude, that is the wamp home page

Comment: No. He's not able to navigate to any of his projects @.@ Its a plain blank page with "It works!" written in it :(

Comment: @Skun, I think you/your friend needs some more education about how a web server works. What you are seeing is the default page. If you want links to the projects, you need to add them yourself! Maybe you're thinking of "Directory Browsing", where if the web server does not find any content to serve, they will show you all the files in the folder?

Comment: If you want directory browsing, delete the `index.htm` file from the `htdocs` folder. You might also need to enable directory browsing in your `httpd.conf` file if you just get a `404` error after deleting the file.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like it works.

That is Apache's default message after a successful install.  It is usually a single HTML file in the htdocs folder.

What are you expecting to see?

So far, I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: yeah, dude: IT WORKS!!!

Comment: Lol. I meant that i wasnt seeing the WAMP homepage.

Comment: @Skun, but, that IS the WAMP homepage!